# Access Foreign Key (m2m) to render template

Tags: django

I think this may be a slightly complicated problem compared to the simple FK lookup. I am trying to output a list in my template but am having some difficulties getting it to display. I think it has to do with a for loop in my template. Any help would be appreciated!

models.py

```
class Option(models.Model):
    relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, verbose_name="disease")
    option = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="treatment Options")

class State(models.Model):
   state = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='state')
   relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, verbose_name="disease")
   relevantoption = models.ManyToManyField(Option, through='StateOption')

class StateOption(models.Model):
   parttstate = models.ForeignKey(State)
   partoption = models.ForeignKey(Option)
   relevantoutcome = models.ManyToManyField(Outcome, through='StateOptionOutcome')
```

views.py

```
def diseasestateoptionlist(request, disease_id, state_id):

    state = get_object_or_404(State, pk=state_id)
    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)

    stateoption = get_list_or_404(StateOption, parttstate=state_id) #probem may be here or in template.html

    diseasestateoptionlist = get_list_or_404(StateOption, parttstate=state_id)

    context = {'state': state, 'disease':disease, 'diseasestateoptionlist': diseasestateoptionlist, 'stateoption':stateoption}
    return render(request, "diseasestateoptionlist.html", context)
```

template.html

```
{{ disease }}
{{ state }}
{% if diseasestateoptionlist %}
 <ul>
{% for option in diseasestateoptionlist %}
   <li><a href="/drui_index/{{disease.id}}/state/option/{{state.id}}/list">{{stateoption.partoption}}</a></li> 
 #problem may be in the stateoption.partoption call
 {% endfor %}
```

Update:
The display is rendering correctly with the for loop but it does not show the options in {{stateoption.partoption}}. So {{disease}}, {{state} are rendering fine. {diseasestateoptionlist} shows the number of values found in the table. But there are no values being displayed (just bullet points from the

statement).

Comment: what difficulties are you having? what is being displayed? can yo upost your option model?

Comment: wrote an update in the original text. I'll also post the option model. HOpe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{% for **option** in diseasestateoptionlist %}

...{{**stateoption**.partoption}}...

Those two have to be the same. :)

Greetings

Comment: Can you explain that to me? I didn't know think that {% for option in diseasestateoptionlist %} was looking at my option table. I feel like I'm going to make the same mistake if I have to do it again.

Comment: Sure, get_list_or_404 returns a list of objects, the for loop iterates over them, option/stateoption or whatever you put [..] {% for **HERE** [..] recieves the instance, to access the instance you have to use the name given at **HERE**